# How to include Dictionary in ASP classic page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dictionary

Hi I am trying to create an .asp page using ASP classic and am having trouble getting it to work. What is the correct way to include the Dictionary datatype in a page?

At the moment I believe the issue is that I am not referencing the System.Collections.Generic in my page, but I cannot figure out where I should put this.

```
Set ssrs = ConRef.Execute("SELECT * FROM tblRefSalesStatus ORDER BY SalesStatus")
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

While !ssrs.EOF

    dict.Add(ssrs("SalesStatusID"), ssrs("SalesStatusDisplayText"))

    ssrs.MoveNext
Next

' gets the display text for the dales status based on the ID
Function GetSalesStatusText(SalesStatusID As String) As String
    Return dict.Item(SalesStatusID)
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic ASP is not VB.Net. It's VBScript. You should try using the VBScript Dictionary object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx

```
Dim d   ' Create a variable.
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.Add "a", "Athens"   ' Add some keys and items.
d.Add "b", "Belgrade"
d.Add "c", "Cairo"
```